# How can i remove duplicate entries in an html table

Tags: javascript

i'm using socket.io for a chat and stats web app. I have a problem figuring out on how to remove duplicate entries in my html table. The duplicate entries happen only because i fetch the api every time someone sends a message, so every time i fetch the api, the stats appear in the table and the table gets too much data.

```
var socket = io("ws://localhost:3000/");

document.getElementById("message").addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("sendbtn").click();
    }, 500);
  }
});

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return "Data will be lost if you leave the page, are you sure?";
};

document.getElementById("message").addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("userbtn").click();
  }
});

var send = () => {
  if (
    document.getElementById("username").value.length == 17 &&
    username.length > 1
  ) {
    socket.emit("message", document.getElementById("message").value);
    document.getElementById("message").value = " ";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Please enter and submit your steam ID");
  }
};

var setusername = () => {
  socket.emit("username", document.getElementById("username").value);
};

var stats = [];

socket.on("user", async (user) => {
  username = user;
  console.log(user);
});

socket.on("stats", (data) => {
  var table = document.getElementById("users-table");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var kd = data.kd;
  cell1.innerHTML = username;
  cell2.innerHTML = kd.toFixed(2);
  cell3.innerHTML = data.time.toFixed() + " h";
});

var username = "";
var message = " ";

socket.on("message", (msg) => {
  message = msg;
  document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML +=
    "<span class=username-bx>" +
    username +
    "</span>" +
    ":" +
    " " +
    msg +
    "<br>";
});

window.setInterval(function () {
  var messagebox = document.getElementById("messages");
  messagebox.scrollTop = messagebox.scrollHeight;
}, 50);
```

For more info you can ask me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the global variable user is set by the socket is a bit weird (I would have expected the user to be part of the response).

Anyway, if you want to only add new messages and stats I would recommend you to work out an id for those (user + msg and user + data.kd? Or whatever will help you to determine that the message is a new one or duplicated) Then maintain a list/set of those. On new msg/stats only add them to your Dom if the id doesn't already exist.